# How to Update Custom Fields from Approval Center in Project Online

Tags: ms-project, project-online

I have noticed that whenever i update a custom fields and send it for approval, it updates the inbuilt fields and not the custom fields in the project plan.

Does anyone know how to update the custom fields automatically once the task is approved from the approval center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a word with Microsoft. It is by design and hence cannot be done. As a workaround we will to do is using JSOM.

You will get an idea based on the below links:

1. Create a Custom Button in Approval Center.
   [https://www.dsouzajoel.com/2017/01/11/custom-ribbon-action-approval-center-project-online-jquery/](https://www.dsouzajoel.com/2016/12/14/update-task-with-approval-center/)
2. Get Assignment IDs from Selected Tasks in Approval Center
   JS Grid helps you to get this information. Below line must be used.

TaskUpdatesComponent.get_GridSatellite().GetJsGridControlInstance().GetCheckSelectionManager().GetCheckedRecordKeys();

3. Update Custom Fields in Project Plan using JSOM
   https://www.dsouzajoel.com/2016/12/14/update-task-with-approval-center/